# Adding short_description to Send Product to a Friend transaction email template

Tags: email-templates, transactional

I am looking for the code to include the product short description (short_description) to my customized Send Product to a Friend transnational email template.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<img src="{{var logo_url}}" width="320" /><br /><br />
Hi, {{htmlescape var=$name}}<br /><br />
{{var sender_name}}  sent you this via Nativitystonescollection: <br /><br/><a href="{{var product_url}}"><img src="{{var product_image}}"  width="125" height="125" border="1" /></a><br />{{var product_name}}<br /><br />
Here is {{var sender_name}}'s message:  {{var message}}<br /><br />
```

Thanks!

Comment: How to add sender's first name alone in subject line?

Answer (score 2):

hi you need send extra parameter to email template

```
so copy
```

**app/code/core/Mage/Sendfriend/Model/Sendfriend.php**

```
to
```

**app/code/local/Mage/Sendfriend/Model/Sendfriend.php**

goto function  send() and

add an extra parameter to template

```
  'product_short_description'  => $this->getProduct()->getShortDescription()
```

after

```
  'product_url'   => $this->getProduct()->getUrlInStore(),
```

add `new html variable  {{var product_short_description}} to email template`

Comment: Thank you for your info. I'm new to Magento so please pardon my ignorance. I followed your instructions but the short description isn't showing up. I'm using Magento 1.9. but noticed that and the sub-folders under app/local .../Mage/Sendfriend/Model/ did not exist so I created the addition folders and copied 'Sendfriend.php'.  

Any further ideas?

Thanks again.

Comment: are you use default magento?

Comment: are you  used html email template?

Comment: Yes, I loaded the default transactional email template for send to a friend and modified it and selected the new template in System > Config > Catalog > EMail to a Friend.

Comment: Magento temple is Modern.

Comment: just copy Sendfriend.php from app/code/core/Mage/Sendfriend/Model/Sendfriend.php  and put it under app/code/local/Mage/Sendfriend/Model/ .According tp you need to create folders

Comment: add this code  "var product_short_description":"product Message" after "var sender_name":"Sender name",

Comment: put full html template to question

Comment: where do I place this code:

add this code "var product_short_description":"product Message" after "var sender_name":"Sender name", –

Comment: are you managing email template from admim>system>Transactional Emails ?

Comment: Here is what my template looks like:


<a href="{{store url=""}}"><img src="{{var logo_url}}" width="320" /></a><br />


Hi, {{htmlescape var=$name}}<br /><br />

{{var sender_name}}  sent you this via Nativitystonescollection: <br /><br/><a href="{{var product_url}}"><img src="{{var product_image}}"  width="125" height="125" border="0" /></a><br /><a href="{{var product_url}}">{{var product_name}}</a><br /><br />


{{var product_short_description}}

<br /><br />


Here is {{var sender_name}}'s message:  {{var message}}<br /><br /><br />  <br />

Comment: are you managing email template from admim>system>Transactional Emails ?

Yes

Comment: My customized Send to a Friend is working OK, I just need to add short description.

Comment: Where do I add this?:

add this code "var product_short_description":"product Message" after "var sender_name":"Sender name", –

Comment: can you please share  php code  by which send email with this template

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: as per as my concern.you  don't  using  magento  default Sendfriend mail functionality. You have some customization.

Comment: So i want to know by  using which mail  function you have sending this meail